# Fiddler how to capture traffic from local program without proxy

Tags: fiddler

Fiddler works great for capturing local web traffic. It even works really well to sniff data from mobile apps. However, I do not know how to get Fiddler to capture data from a local Windows program.

This program is locally installed and has no settings to configure a proxy. Is there someway for Fiddler to gather info?

I see lots of similar questions but they answer always seems to configure a proxy or edit the code. I have no access to the code.

Thanks